# How to implement a queue to arrange a game for several users in a website?

Tags: php, jquery

I know this sounds quite sparse. I know PHP and learning jQuery. My goal is to make a feature in a website which works this way:
1. Any user visits the site and hits "join" to join a queue and wait for a game.
2. When 10 users are in the queue (the minimum for one game) the website alerts the user that a game is ready for them and provides them one link to follow.

That's all... can this be done with jQuery annd PHP? My first idea was to create a DB table called "queue" where the users are entered when they click "join", but my challenge is, how do I make it so the queue table is periodically being checked and the 10 users receive a message in their side with "OK your game is ready follow this link to join"?

I'm not asking for the code, but for the idea and if this can be done with jQuery and PHP...I'm not a pro-programmer so my main doubt is... when a user clicks "join", the execution in his side ends right? so how to keep the site checking the queue asynchronously and alert all users.

Thanks!

Comment: Use jQuery.ajax(); for asynchronously request to a php file with a query to queue table

Comment: and to keep querying the queue table until 10 players are found... a loop with a counter and the counter being updated with the response of the php file which queries the queue, right?